# problem doing chown for a group

Tags: macos, administrator

I just started a new job and got given a new laptop, I am having problems archiving xcode iOS apps.
the command xcode wants to use is:

```
cd /Users/manuel.betancurt/Documents/testeos/iOS/suzo
/usr/sbin/chown -RH manuel.betancurt:MACSC\\Domain\ Users /Users/manuel.betancurt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/suzo-budvdahrkocdbhdzgvybyoizscxk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/suzo/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/suzo.app
```

but I get the error

> chown: MACSC\Domain Users: illegal group name Command SetOwnerAndGroup
> failed with a nonzero exit code

I can see the id for the user, but the group is not working?

So what is the issue?, why is this failing?, is this related to some configuration changed by the sysadmin that prepared the mac?

what is this group "MACSC\Domain\ Users"

Comment: Is your laptop being managed by your company? Look in System Preferences for a Profiles preference. If there is one, poke inside to see how your machine is being managed and what restrictions you may have. A quick word with your IT department may be in order to resolve this.